# Flash power changes automatically

Tags: flash

When i use my SB700 on a tripod, i set the power to +3 as i like to photograph owls that are not very close up in the trees, and as soon as the flash goes off the + sign turns to a - and every photo comes out dark obviously since the power output is low. I use a Nikon d7200 with Godox xpro transmitter and Godox X1 R receiver.
[image]

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: How are you confirming that the flash output is low? Are the lighting conditions changing rapidly? What happens if you use all manual settings instead of TTL and flash exposure compensation?

Comment: Also, I see that you are at a wide flash head zoom (24mm). Is that intentional?

Comment: If your flash power is already maxed out, +3 EV will not give you any more light. Changing the zoom head from 24mm to 120mm will help.

Comment: What focal length lens are you using?

Comment: Also, https://www.audubon.org/news/is-flash-photography-safe-owls

Answer (score 3):

It should revert to the plus sign after about 3 seconds...

It is telling you that the flash does not have near enough power to provide enough light, by at least 3 stops (it will report underexposure as -0.3EV to -3.0EV).

You should zoom the flash head to max/120mm, but I doubt that will help enough.

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities: the flash may be taking its exposure correction from the camera when triggered (in which case you need to correct the setting in-camera).  Or it may correct its display to the exposure it actually has been able to achieve.  You are talking about owls in a tree: that implies a certain distance.  But the flash displays 24mm of zoom DX which is wide angle.  It corresponds more or less to 35mm FX where the flash is specified to have guide number 28m.

Assuming F2.8 and ISO100, you'll have a reach of 10m at EV0, and a reach of about 3.5m at EV+3 (3 stops make for a factor of about 2.8, namely sqrt(8)).

Answer (score 1):

You need to set you exposure compensation on the Godox XPro. When you take the shot, the XPro is going to send a signal to the receiver/flash which will set it to whatever settings it has configured.

It will override anything set on the flash, the XPro is the controller.